# Adding Fancybox to Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fancybox, datatables

I'm looking to implement fancybox within my DataTable. I want to be able to click on the link that is stored in my database and render the stored page within my datatable within a iframe/fancybox and be able to interact with that page. I do not want to be able to see the page unless clicked on.

I'm not completely sure if fancybox is the appropriate choice for this feature and any increased efficiency that can be added to my interpretation of datatables would be awesome. I know I'm asking for a lot.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if(!$con){
    die("Error: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("Test_Data", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Test_DataSet");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST TABLE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/hmtl; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables-1.10.1/media/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="DataTables-1.10.1/media/js/jquery.DataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        @import "DataTables-1.10.1/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import "DataTables-1.10.1/examples/resources/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css";
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#datatables').dataTable();
        })
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 1600,
                maxHeight   : 1200,
                fitToView   : true,
                width       : '100%',
                height      : '100%',
                autoSize    : true,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
    });
    </script>


    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('a.modalGeneric').fancybox({
                type: 'iframe',
                fitToView: true,
                autoSize: true,
                openEffect: 'fade',
                openSpeed: 'slow'
            });
    });
    </script>
    <style> iframe{border: none; width: 20}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
         <table id="datatables" class="hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Building</th>            
                    <th>Floor</th>
                    <th>Number of AP</th>
                    <th>Associated Floor Plans</th>
                    <th>View on WebPage</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                <tr class ="odd gradeX">
                    <td><?php echo $row['Building']; ?></td>             
                    <td><?php echo $row['Floor']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Number_Of_AP']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '<a class="various fancybox.iframe”  href="'.$row['Associated_Floor_Plans'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['Associated_Floor_Plans'].'</a>';?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '<a class="various fancybox.iframe” href="'.$row['View_On_Webpage'].'" target="_blank">View in AMP<'.$row['View_On_Webpage'].'</a>';?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help contributed. Please feel free to scrutinize my work.

Comment: I think fancybox would work just fine for your project , but under the following considerations : (1). Load a single version of jQuery (you are loading 2 in your code)... I would recommend v1.8.3 because the version of fancybox (2). Upgrade at least to fancybox [v1.3.4](http://fancybox.googlecode.com/files/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.zip) ... and also you only need a single version of it (you are loading the obsoletes v1.0.0 and 1.2.3) (3). You may need to initialize the fancybox script within a `dataTable` callback.

Comment: Note: the class `fancybox.iframe` only works with fancybox v2.1.x (2.1.5 the latest so far) so you may need to update to that version or set the API option `type: "iframe"` instead of using the class.

Comment: Thank you so much. Fancybox is now loading from the floor plans stored in google drive but the much more resource intensive page (View_On_Webpage) doesn't seem to be loading in the window that pops up. Any ideas on why. Do you want to see the updated version of my code.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'm attempting to run an entire website in this iframe. Is that possible or is the reason nothing is appearing within the iframe. Basically the result would be a datatables search engine that can view other websites stored in the mysql database without leaving the original search (datatable) page.

Comment: If appears that the server setting (X-Frame-Options set to SAMEORIGIN)is preventing the site that I'm linking to from loading. It's not my own site but is there a workaround for this?

Comment: when sites use X-Frame-Options, there is not too much you can do. There are workarounds like using http://whateverorigin.org/ sample : http://jsfiddle.net/mq779/ however it could have unexpected results when interacting with page contained on the iframe.

Comment: Is there anyway I could use the example approach you listed but have it work for all the URL's in the database instead of just one?